# Error while trying to compile luminance, an open source control system for Phillips Hue

Tags: apt

First I will state that I am one of those new guys who knows literally nothing, so please explain everything in great detail. The main issue here is I don't understand what is going on.

I am trying to install luminance on Ubuntu 16.04. The github is here https://github.com/craigcabrey/luminance (if you look in issues, another person is experiencing the same problem but was never answered)

After installing the packages requested, the README says to-

1. Clone this repository.
2. In the cloned repository, run ./autogen.sh.
3. If everything works, run ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install.

The problem occurs when running ./autogen.sh, and these errors pop up-

```
autogen.sh: reconfigure with autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4 --force
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
configure.ac:8: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
/usr/share/aclocal-1.15/init.m4:29: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:8: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
autogen.sh: autoreconf has failed (1)!
autogen.sh: for the next step, run ./configure
```

I may be wrong, but I believe that is why I get this error when trying to run ./configure-

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE: I have resolved this by cloning from git instead of downloading the zip file.

Comment: Is it enough to run `mkdir m4` before running `./autogen.sh` from the build directory?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) or [CompilingSoftware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware)

Comment: @andrew.46 That got rid of the m4 error line but everything after hasn't changed. I updated the post.

Comment: @J.Starnes I'm looking into that now, I'll let you know if compiling with those methods fixes it.

Comment: Did you `git clone` the repo, or download the zip file? I get the same error as you from the latter - but the former appears to run (with some warnings) and generate a `./configure` script. The `m4` "error" is only a warning AFAIK - I suggest ignoring it at least for now.

Comment: @steeldriver I downloaded the zip and just recently moved it to /usr/local/src/luminance-master.

Comment: In that case I suggest you clone instead `git clone https://github.com/craigcabrey/luminance.git`

Comment: @steeldriver It worked and everything works, took me so long to reply because I recieved an error afterwards because I was missing something from gnome and didn't realize it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the `luminance-master.zip` file has been created without its `.git` directory - and `configure.ac` tries to use `git describe` to pass the software's version number to `AC_INIT`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([luminance],
        m4_esyscmd(echo -n `git describe --always --tags`),
        [https://github.com/craigcabrey/luminance/issues],
        [luminance],
        [https://craigcabrey.github.io/luminance/])
```

A fairly straightforward fix is to edit the `configure.ac` template to hard-code the version string:

```
AC_INIT([luminance],
        [v1.0.1],
        [https://github.com/craigcabrey/luminance/issues],
        [luminance],
        [https://craigcabrey.github.io/luminance/])
```

The diff is simply

```
$ diff configure.ac.bak configure.ac
3c3
<         m4_esyscmd(echo -n `git describe --always --tags`),
---
>         [v1.0.1],
```

Alternatively, forget about the master.zip file and *clone* the repository instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/craigcabrey/luminance.git
```